# Migration from Access to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ms-access, nosql, migrate

I am trying to migrate 3,000,000 records from Microsoft Access to DynamoDB. I am trying to/ cannot find any information on how to most efficiently convert from a relational database to a NoSQL db. Does anyone have a method? Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up migrating to Dynamo from Access?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently different between converting from Access to DynamoDB or from SQL server (or any other relational, b-tree indexed database, for that matter). One thing I can say is, if you have 3 million rows, you want to know that what you are doing is the right thing. NoSQL is very nice, when you have the right use case for it. It downright sucks if you are trying to accomplish something better done through relational data. I don't know your case so I don't have an opinion, but you may want to examine your decision to migrate. There are cloud-based relational database services. 
Consult Amazon's documentation at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/aws-database-migration-service-and-amazon-dynamodb-what-you-need-to-know/ for information on how to get the migration accomplished. 
Beyond that, my approach would be:

A) Use SQL server integration services to extract the table into a SQL instance,

B) upload the data to an Azure instance,

C) Use the amazon database migration service to transfer into DynamoDB.

Your main pitfalls are going to be String encoding, date formats and BLOB/CLOBS. If you have any of the latter, I would suggest writing a short program to handle them separately. Encoding pages can and should be synchronized. Dates are best transferred in the international YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format.